# How to access child elements from XElement object?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XElement object (**element**) which contains the following element (**g**) in it :

```
<g .....>
 <flowRoot id='1'></flowRoot>
 <path id='2'></path>
  ..  
  ...
</g>
```

Now i want to replace the flowRoot element of the g element. For this i tried :

```
element
    .Descendants()
    .Single(g => g.Attribute("id").Value == '1')
    .ReplaceAll(newElement);
```

It gaves me an exception `object reference not set to an instance of an object`. What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: You would probably need to check for Value == "1" since Value is a string type and '1' is of type char.

Comment: So, was my answer helpfull? Did you manage to solve this issue? Please update this SO item...

Answer (score 0):

when I follow your setup and code it like this:

```
XElement element = new XElement("g"
    , new XElement("flowRoot", new XAttribute("id", "1"))
    , new XElement("path", new XAttribute("id", "2"))
    );

XElement newElement = new XElement("flowRoot", new XAttribute("id", "678678"));

element.Descendants().Single(g => g.Attribute("id").Value == "1").ReplaceAll(newElement);
```

all works fine. I did have to replace the single quotes with double quotes around the 1, since it will not compile (as @ryadavilli already pointed out)

My guess is that your 'element' is different than what you think it is, maybe the 'g' node is not the actual root?
What do you get when you test for the 'flowRoot' element like this:

```
XElement flowRoot = element.Descendants("flowRoot").FirstOrDefault();
```

Is `flowRoot` null?